# Merge the advertising tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I suggest the following advertising related tags be made synonyms:

- [ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads), [advertisement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) -> [advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising)

  Ads and advertisement have nearly identical tag wikis which appear to be copied from Wikipedia. The excerpt for ads just says it is an abbreviation of advertisement.
- [adserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adserver) -> [advertisement-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement-server)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280783/burninate-advertising-and-monetization