# Burninate [advertising] and [monetization]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tags [advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising) and [monetization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monetization) attract a lot of off-topic questions and aren't clearly defined. Please burninate them with fire.

Sample questions with these tags:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433164/what-is-your-favorite-mantra-or-piece-of-wisdom
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403421/which-advert-provider-allows-filtering-of-ads
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464253/advertising-how-cost-per-install-ad-networks-counting-installs
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301330/tracking-tool-for-advertising-banners

Comment: There are also tags [ads] and [advertisement]. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251160/merge-the-advertising-tags

Comment: I was going to up-vote, until I realized you were talking about the tags. Then I decided to up-vote, anyway.

Comment: The [monetization] tag has been killed to death with fire. For [advertising], I think you're going to need a bigger boat.

Comment: I have a hairy one @bill, does that help?

Comment: [monetization] was re-created on 10th February, @Bill.

Comment: I am building brainpick.co.uk, it is a Chrome extension, that adds the "Back this question" button, so anyone could back (sponsor) a question. Based on the comments here, there is no chance to add a "Sponsorship" tag to a question?