# ​​[advertisement] [ads] nothing

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

[advertisement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) needs to be merged into [ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads). It's redundant.

Comment: *winning* got the pun on the original post!

Comment: Tag burnination is the biggest on-going pun competition on MSO.

Comment: @Mysticial that only demonstrate the poor naming those tags have.

Comment: How about [advertising](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising)?

Comment: @JasonMArcher good point!

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251160/merge-the-advertising-tags and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280783/burninate-advertising-and-monetization

Comment: Disappointed to see that [tag:admob] was allowed to be a sponsored tag.  I guess money talks.

Comment: @Mysticial: I thought it was the *only* ongoing pun competition on MSO.